# What is the word (if any) that describes one's overall body movement?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word in the English language that refers to the manner in which one moves one's body around?

Similar to 'gait' as *one's manner of walking*, but referring to the overall movement of the body, and not necessarily while walking only, or 'posture' as *the position of one's body while at rest*, but rather describing the way it behaves regardless of whether it is active or not.

'Demeanor', on the other hand, seems to involve one's attitude as well, *the way one behaves toward something/in a particular situation*,  and not just the mechanical movement of the body which is unique in every individual.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Nice first question.

Answer (score 2):

The word **carriage** might be what you are looking for. Here is the definition form the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/carriage):

> the way in which a person moves or keeps their body when they are standing, sitting, or walking

These words can be used about a person's movement or posture, and also about their behaviour:

> [deportment](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deportment): the way a person walks and stands
>
> [bearing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bearing): someone's way of moving and behaving

All of these words are quite formal.